# jQuery $("#someId) vs document.getElementById('someId'), accessing the same DOM element seeing different results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a javascript and jQuery newbie, so this might be a silly question -

I'm experimenting appending rows to an html table and I'm seeing something that strikes me as odd:

when I access my html table using document.getElementById('my_table') i get back object HTMLTableElement, and then I can do things like insertRow(-1), etc., but when I access the same html table via jquery - $('#my_table') i get back object Object, which obviously does not have any of the methods I need. What gives?

Thank you!

Here's the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FOO </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('ready');

        var data = [
          { "amount":"medium",
            "notes":"chicken teriyaki bento box",
            "date_time":"1391029200",
            "type":"lunch",
            "id":18},

          { "amount":"small",
            "notes":"bread, meat balls",
            "date_time":"1391645306",
            "type":"lunch",
            "id":24}
        ]; 

        data.forEach(function(row) {
            for (var key in row) {
              $('body').append(row[key] + ' ');
            }
            $('body').append('<br>');
          });

        // append to table
        (function() {
          var my_table_jq = $("#my_table");
          $('body').append(Object.prototype.toString.call(my_table_jq));

          var my_table_js = document.getElementById('my_table');
          $('body').append(Object.prototype.toString.call(my_table_js));

        })();


      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="my_table" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th><th>Meal</th><th>Amount</th><th>Notes</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're wondering why two different functions give two different results?

Comment: @cookiemonster: No, OP wonders why two functions seemingly doing the same gives two different results. Chill.

Comment: there are good answers below. One thing I'd suggest is that whenever plain JS can do what you want well, do it in plain JS rather than with jQuery. jQuery will always be slower than vanilla JS, and document.getElementById is supported on all browsers with no issue.

Comment: @user13500: OP is using the same function to select other elements *not* by ID, and then using non-native DOM methods on the result. See now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you get through *jQuery* [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) is `jQuery` object not the `DOM` object, you must convert it to DOM object. You can use *indexer* to convert it to `DOM` object. You can also use jQuery [.get( index )](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the DOM object.

*Change*

```
$('#my_table')
```

*To*

```
$('#my_table')[0]
```

or

```
$('#my_table').get(0)
```

> Calling jQuery() (or $()) with an id selector as its argument will
>   return a jQuery object containing a collection of either zero or one
>   DOM element, [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Comment: Yep, just I just read the same thing on jQuery api page. I didn't expect to get back a collection instead of the object I was asking for. I should have RTFM :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When you are accessing objects like `$('#my_table')` you get a jQuery object. You can use the jQuery API to manipulate this object. For instance if you are looking to add remove rows to the table you can do so by using functions like "append". You can refer to the jQuery api documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/). As an example I have edited your code to add your JSON object data to the table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FOO </title>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log('ready');

            var data = [
              {
                  "amount": "medium",
                  "notes": "chicken teriyaki bento box",
                  "date_time": "1391029200",
                  "type": "lunch",
                  "id": 18
              },

              {
                  "amount": "small",
                  "notes": "bread, meat balls",
                  "date_time": "1391645306",
                  "type": "lunch",
                  "id": 24
              }
            ];

            data.forEach(function (row) {
                $('#my_table tbody').append('<tr>');
                $('#my_table tbody').append('<td>' + row['date_time'] + '</td>');
                $('#my_table tbody').append('<td>' + row['type'] + '</td>');
                $('#my_table tbody').append('<td>' + row['amount'] + '</td>');
                $('#my_table tbody').append('<td>' + row['notes'] + '</td>');
                $('#my_table tbody').append('</tr>');
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="my_table" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Meal</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
document.getElementById('my_table'); //returns a HTML DOM Object

$('#my_table');  //returns a jQuery Object

$('#my_table')[0]; //returns a HTML DOM Object
```

> document.getElementById('id') will return a raw DOM object.
>
> $('#id') will return a jQuery object that wraps the DOM object and provides jQuery methods.